# Adjusting the width of Jekyll code snippets

Tags: jekyll

In my Jekyll theme I can add code snippets to my markdown posts using:

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def print_hi(name)
  puts "Hi, #{name}"
end
print_hi('Tom')
#=> prints 'Hi, Tom' to STDOUT.
{% endhighlight %}
```

However this code block is not as wide as I would like. I want it to span a greater width on the screen. Is it possible to adjust it at all? Any pointers on this would be really appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `.highlight { width: 100px; }` at the end of your main css file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix this for my blog.  Edit `_sass/_basscss.sccs` and add a tweak for the figure element:

```
figure {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Setting the width to a fixed value might muck up the layout on mobile devices, so perhaps that's not the best solution.  Also, depending on your theme the code is going to be truncated in a scrolling box anyway even on a desktop browser, so make judicious use of whitespace and forced line breaks.

Comment: Sorry late reply. I tried this but the code snippet is not centered anymore.